# Android spinner calculation with variables

Tags: android, variables, spinner

I have a problem that i can't figure out how to solve. My code is the following:

```
    package com.app.BoomBase;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.LauncherActivity.ListItem;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Distance extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {
    Button Calc;
    Spinner spType, spForce, spWeight;
    double FarstCatch, TrickCatch, MTA, LongDistance ;
    String[] types  = { "Farst Catch", "Trick Catch", "MTA" , "Long Distance" };
    EditText etWeight;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.distance);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FarstCatch = 100;
        TrickCatch = 43.56; 
        MTA = 32.60 ; 
        LongDistance = 25;

        ArrayAdapter<String> AdapterT = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, types);
        spType = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spType);
        AdapterT.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        spType.setAdapter(AdapterT);
        spType.setPrompt("Select Type");
        spType.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        Button Calc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);


        Calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String selected = spType.getSelectedItem().toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Boomerang will apoximately fly this far:" + selected, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
        }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int position = spType.getSelectedItemPosition();
        switch (position){
        case 0:
            double FarstCatch;
            break; 
        case 1: 
            double TrickCatch;
            break;
        case 2: 
            double MTA;
            break;
        case 3: 
            double LongDistance;
            break;
        }
        }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

I want to take the variable that correspond to the seleceted case from the user input (spType), and then use that for a calculation. Exmple: If the user selectes FarstCatch i want to take the number 100 and use it in this calculation: R = m / FarstCatch.

How can i do that ?

**Edit:**
The new code:

```
 package com.app.BoomBase;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Distance extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {
    Button Calc;
    Spinner spType, spForce, spWeight;
    double FarstCatch, TrickCatch, MTA, LongDistance, r ;
    String[] types  = { "Farst Catch", "Trick Catch", "MTA" , "Long Distance" };
    double[] values = {100, 43.56, 32.6, 25};
    EditText etWeight;
    int etNum;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.distance);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FarstCatch = 100;
        TrickCatch = 43.56; 
        MTA = 32.60 ; 
        LongDistance = 25;


        ArrayAdapter<String> AdapterT = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, types);
        spType = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spType);
        AdapterT.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        spType.setAdapter(AdapterT);
        spType.setPrompt("Select Type");
        spType.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        etWeight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etWeight);
        Button Calc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        Calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String etValue = etWeight.getText().toString();
                etNum = Integer.parseInt(etValue);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Boomerang will apoximately fly this far:" + r , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
    }

    public void onItemSelected1(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
          // value corresponds to the selected spType
          double value = values[arg2];

          r = etNum/value;  
}

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int position = spType.getSelectedItemPosition();
        switch (position){
        case 0:
            double FarstCatch;
            break; 
        case 1: 
            double TrickCatch;
            break;
        case 2: 
            double MTA;
            break;
        case 3: 
            double LongDistance;
            break;
        }
}

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

But it still don't work.. How can this be ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create another array for values corresponding to types array.

```
double[] values = {100, 43.56, 32.6, 25};
```

Next, implement onItemSelected() as follows -

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
  // value corresponds to the selected spType
  double value = values[arg2];

  // Do your calculation
  //double R = m/value; 
}
```

**Note**: arg2 is the selected item position so need to use getSelectedItem()

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
```

Sample Code:

```
public class Distance extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {
    Button Calc;
    Spinner spType, spForce, spWeight;
    double selectedValue, r;
    String[] types  = { "Farst Catch", "Trick Catch", "MTA" , "Long Distance" };
    double[] values = {100, 43.56, 32.6, 25};
    EditText etWeight;
    int etNum;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.distance);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ArrayAdapter<String> AdapterT = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, types);
        spType = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spType);
        AdapterT.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        spType.setAdapter(AdapterT);
        spType.setPrompt("Select Type");
        spType.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        etWeight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etWeight);
        Button Calc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        Calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String etValue = etWeight.getText().toString();
                etNum = Integer.parseInt(etValue);
                r = etNum/selectedValue; 
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Boomerang will apoximately fly this far:" + r , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
          // value corresponds to the selected spType
          selectedValue = values[arg2]; 
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite following...?

Comment: Okay .. so you want to do some calculation based on the user input (spType). Your code is fine so when the user selects a particular item in the spinner (spType) then onItemSelected() will get called and the position of the selected item is passed as arg2. Now this position corresponds to the types array .. right? so use the same position to get the value (e.g. 100) from the values array which i showed in my answer.

Comment: I have now tried what you have suggested, but i get a result: 0.0 no matter what i do.. Why is that ?

Comment: You need to calculate r = etNum/value inside onClick(). Check my code.